# How to add comments to a post

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

Im trying to build a website where people can post messages, and other people can comment on it

I have set up an express website with Node. Made it so people can add new posts.

Checked google for tutorials and found alot of "How to make a blog in express" tutorials on Medium; but i'd love to read tutorial where they also show how to add comments.

My request is; could someone point me towards a tutorial that shows me how to make this?

Answer (score 0):

1. Setup mysql server and [connect your nodeJS](https://www.w3schools.com/nodejs/nodejs_mysql.asp) with this database

   2. Add a form to your site which contains a postId & maybe poster's name & comment content [ref](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/133925/javascript-post-request-like-a-form-submit)
   3. Create an API Endpoint which handles [incoming POST requests](https://medium.com/@purposenigeria/build-a-restful-api-with-node-js-and-express-js-d7e59c7a3dfb)
   4. Do MySQL Query to fetch data from db and display it.